# want to display only time using the below code

Tags: javascript, angular

want to display only the time that is 10:00 but not the current date from statement

```
$scope.date = new Date (new Date().toDateString() + ' ' +'10:00');
```

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: the above code enables me to get the date along with the time . but i want to display only the static time i.e 10:00 which is mentiond in code

Comment: Edit your question and add more details

Answer (score 1):

You can set the time using setHours, setMinutes and setSeconds to the Date object.

```js
let date= new Date();
date.setHours(10);
date.setMinutes(0);
date.setSeconds(0)

console.log(date.toLocaleString())
//To show only time
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date pipe` to display time in a specific format.

HTML:

```
{{valueDate | date: 'h:mm a'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me

```
   display: any;
   time: Date = new Date();
   this.display = this.time.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/:\d{2}\s/, ' ');
```

Here is the working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vzubmd

Answer (score 0):

Use the date pipe like for your variable - {{date | date: 'hh:mm a'}}